# Tails OS : SSH tunnel works but not for tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, ssh

I set up an ssh tunnel on Tails ( tor -> tunnel -> internet ) to reach tor-unfriendly sites, it does seem to work ( I tested it with electrum ), but when I try to reach it with tor browser by changing the socks5 proxy port, I only get "unable to connect".
It there some kind of additional secturity for tor browser that prevents it from using another proxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are extra tests in the browser which try to stop it using a proxy other than Tor's proxy, by comparing the port reported by Tor over the Control Port with the one defined in the proxy settings.

And there are further restrictions set by the firewall that limit your ability to make connections to local services other than those explicitly allowed by the `ferm` packet filter rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ; I took care of "ferm" correctly since electrum is able to connect. Any clue where to look for to lift restrictions in tor browser? I don't see anything like that in settings.

Comment: They're hardcoded into Tor Button: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbutton.git/tree/src/chrome/content/torbutton.js?h=maint-1.9.7#n1404 which is why tools like `filtor` have to spoof the responses to certain commands to work properly with Tor Browser: https://github.com/mutantmonkey/filtor/blob/master/filtor#L186-L191